# Mineflayer.js Bot crashes with Bot.chat()

Tags: javascript, minecraft

bot.chat() isn't working, i tried using await and not using it, it says Cannot read properties of undefined.
here is my code and error log.
this is the library: https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer, it is using minecraft-protocol

```
mineflayer = require('mineflayer');
let requirements = {
    'host':'mc.ip.net',
    'port':'88888',
    'version':'1.19.2'
};

class MCBot{
    // Constructor
    constructor(username){
        this.username = username;
        this.host = requirements['host'];
        this.port = requirements['port'];
        this.version = requirements['version'];

        this.initBot()
    };
    // Init Bot Instance
    initBot(){
        this.bot = mineflayer.createBot({
            'username': this.username,
            'host': this.host,
            'port': this.port,
            'version': this.version
        });
        this.initEvents()
    }
    // Init Bot Events
    initEvents(){
        // Login Event
        this.bot.on('login', ()=>{
            let botSocket = this.bot._client.socket;
            console.log(`[${this.username}] Logged in to ${botSocket.server ? botSocket.server : botSocket.host}`);
        });
        // Disconnect Event
        this.bot.on('end', ()=>{
            console.log(`[${this.username}] Disconnected`);
            // Reconnection Attempt
            setTimeout(()=> this.initBot, 2000);
        });
        // Error Event
        this.bot.on('error', (err)=>{
            if(err.code==='ECONNREFUSED'){
                console.log(`[${this.username}] Failed to Reconnect to ${err.address}:${err.port}`);
            }else{
                console.log(`[${this.username}] Unhandled Error: ${err}`);
            }
        });
        // Spawn Event
        this.bot.on('spawn', async ()=>{
            console.log(`[${this.username}]  Spawned in`);
            await this.bot.waitForTicks(0)
            this.bot.chat(`${this.username}'s Ready!`);
            /*
            await this.bot.waitForTicks(60);
            this.bot.chat("Goodbye!");
            this.bot.quit();
            */
        });
    }
}
new MCBot("Bob")
// let bots = ["Bob"]
// for(var i = 0; i<bots.length; i++){
//     bots.push(new MCBot(bots[i]))
//     console.log("Bot added")
// }
```

Here is the error i get, it seems to have some problem with lenght but i cant find anything

```
[Bob] Logged in to undefined
[Bob]  Spawned in
TypeError: Serialization error for play.toServer : SizeOf error for undefined : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at Object.previousMessages (eval at compile (C:\Users\xianc\Desktop\CHRIS\Minecraft\Bots\node_modules\protodef\src\compiler.js:258:12), <anonymous>:175:37)
    at Object.packet_chat_message (eval at compile (C:\Users\xianc\Desktop\CHRIS\Minecraft\Bots\node_modules\protodef\src\compiler.js:258:12), <anonymous>:599:37)
    at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\xianc\Desktop\CHRIS\Minecraft\Bots\node_modules\protodef\src\compiler.js:258:12), <anonymous>:1222:64)
    at packet (eval at compile (C:\Users\xianc\Desktop\CHRIS\Minecraft\Bots\node_modules\protodef\src\compiler.js:258:12), <anonymous>:1270:9)
    at CompiledProtodef.sizeOf (C:\Users\xianc\Desktop\CHRIS\Minecraft\Bots\node_modules\protodef\src\compiler.js:89:14)
    at e.message (C:\Users\xianc\Desktop\CHRIS\Minecraft\Bots\node_modules\protodef\src\compiler.js:96:40)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\xianc\Desktop\CHRIS\Minecraft\Bots\node_modules\protodef\src\utils.js:50:16)
    at CompiledProtodef.createPacketBuffer (C:\Users\xianc\Desktop\CHRIS\Minecraft\Bots\node_modules\protodef\src\compiler.js:96:20)
    at Serializer.createPacketBuffer (C:\Users\xianc\Desktop\CHRIS\Minecraft\Bots\node_modules\protodef\src\serializer.js:12:23)
    at Serializer._transform (C:\Users\xianc\Desktop\CHRIS\Minecraft\Bots\node_modules\protodef\src\serializer.js:18:18) {
  field: 'play.toServer'
}
[Bob] Unhandled Error: TypeError: Serialization error for play.toServer : SizeOf error for undefined : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
[Bob] Disconnected
```

I tried using await and not using it but it does the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read from the official repository:
https://github.com/PrismarineJS/mineflayer

There is no support for versions later than 1.19 yet

The main problem is caused by the chat signing system made by Microsoft in the latest updates.

So we have to wait until mineflayer and its libraries are updated!